# Which library for voxel data structure?

Tags: c++, raycasting, voxels

I'm working in C++ with large voxel grids in a scientific context and I'm trying to decide, which library to use. Only a fraction of the voxel grid holds values - but might be several per voxel (e.g. struct), which are determined by raytracing. I'm not trying to render anything, but I have to determine the potential number of rays passing though  the entire target area, thus an *awful* lot of ray-box computations will have to be caluculated and preferebly very fast...

So far, I found

- OpenVDB http://www.openvdb.org/
- Field3d http://sites.google.com/site/field3d/

The latter appeals a bit more, because it seems simpler/easier to use.

My question is: Which of them would be more suited if put to use in tasks, which are not aimed at rendering/visualization? Which one is faster/better when computing  a lot of ray-box-intersections (no viewpoint-dependent culling possible)? Suggestions, anyone?

In any case, I want to use an existing C++ library and not write a kdTree/Octree etc. myself. Don't have the time for inventing the wheel anew.

Comment: Well, I would suggest openVDB, since its documentation is great. There are also many examples how to apply level set methods on the grid using (many existing) stencils.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise

1. [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/)
2. [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/)
3. [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/)

I have personally used the first two. However, VTK is also a popular alternative. All three of them support voxel based rendering.

Comment: Great, but I explicitly do not want to render anything. Those libraries are far to large to handle just for a nice data structure.